# Jquery hover in out issue

Tags: jquery

Why doesn´t this work? 
Explanation: I have a container (div with .hover). On hover, .thumbtxt2 should slide in from the left, which it does, but only at the first time. After that, it slides in from the right.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j(".hover").hover(function () {
        $j(this).find('.thumbtxt2').css("left", "-220");
        if ($j(window).width() > 1050) {
            $j(this).find('.thumbimg').stop().animate({
                opacity: .0
            }, 200);

            $j(this).find('.thumbtxt2').stop().animate({
                left: 0
            }, 200);
        } else {
            $j(this).find('.thumbimg').stop().animate({
                opacity: .5
            }, 200);
        };
    },
    function () {
        if ($j(window).width() > 1050) {
            $j(this).find('.thumbimg').stop().animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 200);
            $j(this).find('.thumbtxt2').stop().animate({
                left: 220
            }, 200, function () {
                $j(this).find('.thumbtxt2').css("left", "-220");
            });
        } else {
            $j(this).find('.thumbimg').stop().animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 200);
        };
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: what version of jQuery?

Comment: Can you add a jsFiddle to illustrate the problem?

Comment: you should store the object instead of searching (.find) the objects repeatedly.

Comment: Forgot the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TZmYG/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) version of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for possible dynamic elements of matching selector.  Some thing like:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.hover', function(e) {
        var t = $(this).find('.thumbimg'),
            t2 = $(this).find('.thumbtxt2').css('left', -220);
        if ($(window).width() < 9999) {
            t.stop().animate({ opacity: .0 }, 200);
            t2.stop().animate({ left: 0 }, 200);
        }
        else {
            t.stop().animate({ opacity: .5 }, 200);
        };
    })
    .on('mouseleave', '.hover', function(e) {
        var t = $(this).find('.thumbimg'),
            t2 = $(this).find('.thumbtxt2');
        if ($(window).width() < 9999) {
            t.stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 200);
            t2.stop().animate({ left: 220 }, 200);
        }
        else {
            t.stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 200);
        };
    })
});
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
```

## Example

Comment: Thanks for optimizing the code. But it doesn´t yet do what i was looking for. Here´s a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TZmYG/

Answer (score 0):

For some reason,  `t2 = $(this).find('.thumbtxt2').css("left", "-220");` doesn´t work.
Using .animate() `t2 = $(this).find('.thumbtxt2').animate({ left: -220 },0);` works.
The complete function on mouseout isn´t needed then.

Here´s the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/u7EaQ/2/

Comment: what is the problem. It is exactly want you want.

Comment: Well that´s the answer to my original problem.